# How do I remove a box-shadow effect from an element when another element is hovered?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Structure:

```
 <div class="box">
      <div class="inner_box">
      </div>
 </div>
```

.inner_box has a box-shadow effect.  When .box is hovered I want to remove shadow effect from .inner_box.  Besides using JQuery, is there another way I can do this, preferably CSS3?

Please also show me examples of how i can do this in JQuery.  Thanks!

Comment: Use the jQuery method `hover` if you want to use jQuery. Otherwise, the CSS option provided in another answer is going to be your simplest action. I recommend going with that one, unless we all completely misunderstand the question

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Just use this css this will work **[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/lvtrvd/fB6mj/)**

```
.box:hover .inner_box {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Here's a css only solution.

```css
.inner_box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black;
}

.box:hover .inner_box {
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="inner_box">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

You must reset the `box-shadow` back to its default state: `none`:

```
.box:hover .inner_box {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add this property on hover

```
color: none;
```